# Progress View в Android

Tags: android

Как именно реализовать в Android Progress View ? (Имею в виду именно view элемент, который динамически может меняться в зависимости от определённых параметров в Activity).

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=progressbar Вот здесь полно красивых примеров

Comment: @АндроидАндроид спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Делаем разметку.
2. Находим нужный элемент.
3. Устанавливаем анимацию в зависимости от параметра у этого объекта.

Очень часто используется progressbar в связке с ObjectAnimator.
Пример:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myProgressBar, "progress", level);
```